# regex to check string is certain length

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to write a regex to match pairs of cards `(AA, KK, QQ ... 22)` and I have the regex `([AKQJT2-9])\1`. The problem I have is that this regex will match `AA` as well as `AAbc` etc. Is there a way to write the regex such that I can specify I want to match `([AKQJT2-9])\1` and only that (i.e. no more characters after).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose the regex in `^` and `$`:

```
^([AKQJT2-9])\1$
```

`^` is the "start-of-string" anchor, and `$` is the "end-of-string" anchor. If your regex flavor supports it, `\A` and `\Z` might be an even better choice since `^` and `$` can also match start/end of a line in a multiline string, depending on your regex engine and configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You mean, like this ?

```
^([AKQJT2-9])\1$
```

It will only match if the string is "AA", "KK", …

If you want to capture both characters, but not the rest of the string, you'll have to use another parenthesis

```
($match,$unused) = $string ~= (([AKQJT2-9])\2); # in perl
```